# Bottom of my charcoal grill keeps falling out

Tags: grilling, barbecue, charcoal

I got a small charcoal kettle grill from Craigslist recently. I can't seem to get the little dish on the botton that holds the charcoal(?) to stay attached to it. It tends to just fall out when I put it in.

[image]

Not sure if this metal piece is supposed to do something? I've been googling but no luck so far. It's the [ProLight 14-inch grill](https://www.meijer.com/shop/en/outdoor-cooking/portable-grills/prolight-14-x22-portable-kettle-charcoal-grill/p/70882078017) from Meijer... I've never grilled before, is this normal? Am I supposed to glue it in or something?

[image]

Comment: Maybe that is why it was on Craigslist? Some unscrupulous person selling broken merchandise?

Comment: You're surely not supposed to glue something which will heat the glue out of existence the first time you use it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Push & twist, very similar mechanism to a bayonet-fitting light bulb.

Three hooks go over three pins, then you turn it to lock.

[image]

I cannot tell from the photos whether the pins are in situ.

Just in case it's not entirely clear from that brief description, you lift the 'bucket' up underneath, it should fit outside the flange on the main structure. Then you slot it over the three pins & twist slightly so it drops into the little locks.

Comment: Sorry, what three pins are you referring to?

Comment: There should be one at the point I marked in the top unit, & another 2 equidistant from it, pointing outwards from the structure - like a 3-point bayonet mount - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount#/media/File:Bayonet-mount-01.svg

Comment: Guess I found the problem.... There are no pins. Must be missing a part :( I'll see if I can substitute something as a replacement. But you helped me realize that I'm not crazy-- thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image: this photo] Given this photo I found, it seems that the rod in your second photo is necessary.  Unfortunately, I can't find alternate perspectives or an instruction manual. It would certainly not glue in, but it might push through allowing the bottom to hang.  Then it could be removed to clean the ashes.

Comment: Typically with the hangers that the OP has circled there are 2 or 3 of them to hold a unit in place before it is properly retained. In this case, as you pointed out, by the rod. The only thing I would add, is that heat has a tendency to warp and fatigue metal so when you go to put the tray on the hangers, be sure to line them up carefully so that you can slide that rod through easily.

Comment: I suspect that the rod is used to open/close what appear to be air-flow holes within the inner second layer. It possibly feeds through one of the air-holes and then through a single hole in the outside and inside to create a pivot point. There is a [manual on amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Char-Broil-13301719-Portable-Kettle-Charcoal/dp/B007HIW0AG) for a similar (updated?) grill  The attachment needs 3 flanged pins to hold it onto the tray as others have described.

Comment: The rod is too big for that hole (specifically the small hole circled by Tetsujin above)...I will check out the manual bob1 mentioned.